# Issue loading assets into flutter project

Tags: tensorflow, flutter

I'm trying to load a TFLite model into flutter but I'm getting the exception "failed to load model". I've loaded the asset through the yaml, imported the TFLite plugin and made sure the file path is right but I keep getting the same exception printed. I've tested the model with python and it works so I'm just trying to get it to work with flutter now.

**Code:**

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

const String TF = "image_classifier";
//const String yolo = "Tiny YOLOv2";

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: TfliteHome(),
    );
  }
}

class TfliteHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TfliteHomeState createState() => _TfliteHomeState();
}

class _TfliteHomeState extends State<TfliteHome> {
  String _model = TF;
  File _image;

  double _imageWidth;
  double _imageHeight;
  bool _busy = false;

  List _recognitions;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _busy = true;

    loadModel().then((val) {
      setState(() {
        _busy = false;
      });
    });
  }

  loadModel() async {
    Tflite.close();
    try {
      String res;
        res = await Tflite.loadModel(
          model: "assets/image_classifier.tflite",
          labels: "assets/image_labels.txt",
        );
      print(res);
    } on PlatformException {
      print("Failed to load the model");
    }
  }

  selectFromImagePicker() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image == null) return;
    setState(() {
      _busy = true;
    });
    predictImage(image);
  }

  predictImage(File image) async {
    if (image == null) return;

    if (_model == TF) {
      await TFModel(image);
    }

    FileImage(image)
        .resolve(ImageConfiguration())
        .addListener((ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
          setState(() {
            _imageWidth = info.image.width.toDouble();
            _imageHeight = info.image.height.toDouble();
          });
        })));

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
      _busy = false;
    });
  }

  TFModel(File image) async {
    var recognitions = await Tflite.detectObjectOnImage(
        path: image.path,
        model: "image_classifier",
        threshold: 0.3,
        imageMean: 0.0,
        imageStd: 255.0,
        numResultsPerClass: 3);

    setState(() {
      _recognitions = recognitions;
    });
  }

  List<Widget> renderBoxes(Size screen) {
    if (_recognitions == null) return [];
    if (_imageWidth == null || _imageHeight == null) return [];

    double factorX = screen.width;
    double factorY = _imageHeight / _imageHeight * screen.width;

    Color blue = Colors.red;

    return _recognitions.map((re) {
      return Positioned(
        left: re["rect"]["x"] * factorX,
        top: re["rect"]["y"] * factorY,
        width: re["rect"]["w"] * factorX,
        height: re["rect"]["h"] * factorY,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
            color: blue,
            width: 3,
          )),
          child: Text(
            "${re["detectedClass"]} ${(re["confidenceInClass"] * 100).toStringAsFixed(0)}%",
            style: TextStyle(
              background: Paint()..color = blue,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 15,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    List<Widget> stackChildren = [];

    stackChildren.add(Positioned(
      top: 0.0,
      left: 0.0,
      width: size.width,
      child: _image == null ? Text("No Image Selected") : Image.file(_image),
    ));

    stackChildren.addAll(renderBoxes(size));

    if (_busy) {
      stackChildren.add(Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ));
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("TFLite Demo"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.image),
        tooltip: "Pick Image from gallery",
        onPressed: selectFromImagePicker,
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: stackChildren,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Pubspec.yaml:**

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
  - assets/image_classifier.tflite
  - assets/image_labels.txt
```

File Path:
[image: File path is correct as well which is why I'm confused]

Comment: Did you add them to pubspec.yaml? Include the assets snippet from that in the question.

Comment: Yes I've added the assets into pubspec.yaml and I've added that portion of the code into my original post

Comment: There should be an indentation in line which says `- assets/image_classifier.tflite` and `- assets/image_labels.txt`.  Does indentation exist in `pubspec.yaml`? Because in the above code snippet it does not exist.

Comment: I indented the assets in pubspec.yaml but it still isn't working. It's still printing failed to load model.

Comment: Are you able to load the asset yourself using root bundle? Just to check that it is available.

Comment: yes the root bundle contains no errors and it loads fine there. That's what's confusing me because it indicates the file path is correct. There are also no errors in the main.dart, the exception only occurs when I run the code.

Answer (score 0):

Android
In android/app/build.gradle, add the following setting in android block.

```
  aaptOptions {
    noCompress 'tflite'
    noCompress 'lite'
}
```

worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```dart
assets:
  - assets/image_classifier.tflite // also not the two-space indentation
  - assets/image_labels.txt
```

should be without the 'assets' in the paths.

```dart
assets:
  - image_classifier.tflite
  - image_labels.txt
```